# Django Template print items from a Dictionary of Querysets

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view that looks like this:

```
def CarteleraPeliculaToday(request, slugpelicula):
    city = request.session["ciudad"]
    today = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=5)).date()  # date: Ecuador time zone
    pelicula = Pelicula.objects.get(slug=slugpelicula)
    espanol_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1)
    espanol_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1)
    espanol_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, vip=1)
    espanol_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, xd=1)
    espanol_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", gtmax=1)
    espanol = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol")
    espanol_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", vip=1)
    espanol_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", xd=1)
    subtitulada_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1)
    subtitulada_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1)
    subtitulada_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, vip=1)
    subtitulada_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, xd=1)
    subtitulada_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", gtmax=1)
    subtitulada = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada")
    subtitulada_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", vip=1)
    subtitulada_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", xd=1)

    #Creating a dictionary of all types of funciones querysets
    funciones = {'espanol': espanol, 'subtitulada': subtitulada, 'espanol_3d': espanol_3d, 'subtitulada_3d': subtitulada_3d, 'espanol_3d_gtmax': espanol_3d_gtmax,
'espanol_vip': espanol_vip, 'espanol_xd': espanol_xd, 'subtitulada_3d_gtmax': subtitulada_3d_gtmax,  'subtitulada_3d_vip': subtitulada_3d_vip,  'espanol_3d_vip': espanol_3d_vip, 'espanol_3d_xd': espanol_3d_xd, 'espanol_gtmax': espanol_gtmax,
'subtitulada_3d_xd': subtitulada_3d_xd, 'subtitulada_gtmax': subtitulada_gtmax, 'subtitulada_vip': subtitulada_vip, 'subtitulada_xd': subtitulada_xd}

    #Removing empty element from funciones dictionary
    for x in list(funciones.keys()):
        if not (funciones[x]).exists():
            del funciones[x]
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    context = {'pelicula': pelicula, 'funciones': funciones}
    return render_to_response('cartelera-pelicula.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my template looks like this:

```
{% for key,value in funciones.items %}
            {{key}}
            {% for queryset in value %}
                {% for item in queryset %}
                    {{item}}
                    <br/>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Example(from ipdb):

```
(Pdb) funciones
{'espanol_3d_gtmax': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d_vip': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d_xd': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_xd': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_vip': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol': [<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>, <Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_gtmax': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>]}
<type 'dict'>
```

Now accessing a value:

```
funciones['espanol']
[<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>, <Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>]
type(funciones['espanol'])
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

And finally accessing an item from the Queryset:

```
(Pdb) funciones['espanol'][0]
<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>
type(funciones['espanol'][0])
<class 'core_app.models.Funcion'>
```

The problem is that the template throws this error:

```
'Funcion' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    //127.0.0.1:8000/cartelera/sebas-el-genio/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Funcion' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many for loop levels.  From the first for-loop 'value' will contain the query set object.  The second for-loop will iterate over the results of each query set, i.e. the 'queryset' loop variable will contain individual instances of the Function model.  The third for-loop 'for item in queryset ' is extraneous.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Can a ask you a question about regrouping this stuff on my template or should I open a new one?